# How to convert a Scalar Valued Function to Table Valued Function?

Tags: sql-server

I need to use cross apply in an update statement to avoid calling function each time inside a where clause.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I think we'll need more information about your situation to help you here. What is the code for your current Scalar Function and what is an example of an SQL query where it is being used? The more effort you put into your question, the better answer you will get.

Comment: You need to review StackOverflows help pages on how to ask a question. You get a badge when you finish reading it and it will help you greatly. Also your title doesn't correlate to the body of your question